# Firefox not refreshing all tabs when it opens

Tags: firefox

I upgraded recently from Firefox 12 to Firefox 17, now when I open up the browser (set to open up with all the tabs that were opened when it was closed last), it doesn't refresh each tab.  I now have to click on each tab before it will refresh.

Is there a way to get the old behavior of all tabs refreshing on open?

Comment: Are you using any extension like `tabmixplus`?

Comment: In FF option under `Tab` section there would be an option `Don't load tabs until selected.` unmarked it and check then.

Comment: Personally, I would just right click the tabs bar and refresh all. But well. Automatic is best, eh.

Comment: @LanceRoberts as you said done. :)

Comment: Just further information: This feature is known as "load tabs on demand" and it helps prevent slow restarts and prevents your unused tabs from eating memory when you restore sessions. Useful for most users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FF open the `Option` menu and under `Tab` section uncheck the option **Don't load tabs until selected**.